# Tensorflow support for android API 15

Tags: android, tensorflow

Does tensorflow have support for android API 15?

Here is a link to tensorflow android demo:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android

It says: A device running Android 5.0 (API 21) or higher is required to run the demo due to the use of the camera2 API, although the native libraries themselves can run on API >= 14 devices.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the camera2 API, then you need android 5.0(API 21) or higher, but if not, then anything equal to or higher than API 14 should work

Comment: Does that mean that I should be able to use the prebuilt tensorflow .jar libraries they used in the example for purpoces of my project without including camera2 API and be safe to run it on android API 15?

Comment: yes it does. If i answered your question please accept it as the answer

Comment: no you didn't. I tried using those libraries on API<21 and the program crashed while loading the libraries.

Comment: Well that doesn&#39;t make sense because API 21 is enough for the camera2 API also. So it must be something in your code or how you set up your libraries. Double check it

Comment: The thing is that the same project works for API >=21